# Skipping a character in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to write a code that is reading data from one file and writing it to another file and it should also include the functionality that it should skip a specific character from my input file and then write it to the other file.

```
import java.io.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Opening the streams
        FileReader in = new FileReader("input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( in );
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            in .read();
            bw.write((char) c);
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

Say I want to skip character `a` from input file data, and my input file contains `Name: abc`.

I want to have `Nme: bc` to be written in it's output file. But instead I'm getting `Nm:bc` in the output file.

I also tried using the `skip()` method of `BufferedReader` in it but it is still not giving the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skip()` isn't what you want.  You also have an extra `read()` call, so the loop is reading two characters but only writing one of them.  Just check your character and don't write it if it's the one you want to skip:

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
  char asChar = (char) c;
  if (asChar != charToSkip)
    bw.write(asChar);
}
```